# Flask + Flask-RESTful: Match specific variables to routes

Tags: python, flask, routes, flask-restful

How can I achieve the following?

```
# only if model_type in ['a', 'b', 'c']
api.add_resource(FooAPI, '/<string:model_type'>

# only if model_type in ['x', 'y', 'z']
api.add_resource(BarAPI, '/<string:model_type'>
```

Rather than having the following code:

```
api.add_resource(FooAAPI, '/a'>
api.add_resource(FooBAPI, '/b'>
api.add_resource(FooCAPI, '/c'>

api.add_resource(BarXAPI, '/x'>
api.add_resource(BarYAPI, '/y'>
api.add_resource(BarZAPI, '/z'>
```

Comment: Do you mean you have multiple URL for your resource? You want to have only one resource that can handle multiple urls?

Comment: I want 1 resource for multiple urls, but I also need the variable `model_type` passed as well.

Comment: If your URLs are limited to a,b,c or x,y,z you can link them to FooAPI Or BarAPI each in one command, if thats what you want.

Comment: They are not limited to those and I want to dynamically redirect them to the corresponding API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `any` converter with your desired path and work with media_type as a variable at the same time:

```py
api.add_resource(FooAPI, '/<any(a, b, c):model_type>')
api.add_resource(BarAPI, '/<any(x, y, z):model_type>')
```

If you want them to be dynamic:

```
FooAPIOptions = ['a', 'b', 'c']

api.add_resource(
    FooAPI, "/<any({}):model_type>".format(str(FooAPIOptions)[1:-1]))
```

A simple app would be:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


class FooAPI(Resource):
    def get(self, model_type=None):
        print(model_type) # for example it prints a for "/a" path
        return {'hello': 'world'}


FooAPIOptions = ['a', 'b', 'c']

api.add_resource(
    FooAPI, "/<any({}):model_type>".format(str(FooAPIOptions)[1:-1]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```